Counting the number of local minima of a function that is the sum of square roots of cosines
Suppose you are given a set of functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$. Every function is defined as follows
$$f_i(x) = \sqrt{1+C^2_i-2C_i\cos (x-D_i)}$$
where $0<C_i<1$ and $0\leq D_i<2\pi$ are real-valued constants and $x\in \mathbb R$. Now we restrict $x$ to an interval $]a,b[$, s.t.,
\begin{align}
\forall i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)<f_j(x) &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)>f_j(x) \\
\forall i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)<f_j'(x) &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)>f_j'(x) \\
\forall i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)<f_j''(x) &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)>f_j''(x) \\
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)<0 &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)>0 \\
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)<0 &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)>0 \\
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)<0 &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)>0
\end{align}
In words within the interval $]a,b[$ the following holds:

there is a strict total order over all functions
there is a strict total order of their first derivative (although it does not need to be the same order)
there is a strict total order of their second derivative (although it does not need to be the same order)
no function intersects the $x$-axis
no function has an extremum
no function has an inflection point

Question: How many minima can the function $f_{\Sigma}(x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)$ have within the interval $]a,b[$?
My hope is that the answer to the question is that there can only be one or a constant number of minima, but I would also be happy with any polynomial upper OR exponential lower bound.
What I've tried:
Initially I hoped that the minimum of the sum function would necessarily coincide with a point of the summands, of which there are only $O(n)$, like extrema and inversion points. This does not seems to be true. Then I tried: "Between any two minima of the sum, there has to be a minimum/maximum/inversion point of a summand function", but no such statement seems to be true either. I am not entirely convinced that a charging argument will not work, but I have not been able to find the right angle.
Next I have tried to accumulate the functions into a constant number of functions by grouping them into four sets $F^+_+, F^+_-, F^-_+$ and $F^-_-$, s.t., any function in the set $F^+_-$ has positive first derivative and negative second derivative (and similar for the other three sets). Summing up all of the functions in these sets yields four functions $$
f^+_+(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^+_+} f(x),~~~
f^+_-(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^+_-} f(x),~~~
f^-_+(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^-_+} f(x),~~~
f^-_-(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^-_-} f(x)
$$
and we can observe that we retain that for, e.g., $f^+_-$ the first derivative is entirely positive and the second is entirely negative within $]a,b[$ (and similar for $f^+_+, f^-_-, f^-_+$). Note that these function do not necessarily have a total order anymore, nor do their derivatives. The hope was that reducing the number of functions to just 4 would be helpful, but I could not figure out how to proceed from here.
I have also tried to plot these functions in Mathematica and I have not encountered any instance with more than $n$ minima, which is where my suspicion comes from that the answer is $O(n)$.
Alternative follow up question: If it is for some reason not possible to give any upper bound on the number of minima, what would be a sufficient property of these functions to obtain one?
This question has been asked a couple of days ago on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, but there haven't been any answers yet.

It seems this question isn't asked correctly, seeing that it has gathered no interaction whatsoever. I would actually be happy to know why that is (question is trivial, question doesn't make sense, question is too wordy/not detailed enough, simply asked at an inopportune time, there's no interest in this question on this webpage, ...)
